# TYPO3 TCA Overriding exists file

Tags: file, typo3

I have an issue like this with TYPO3.
I have an object, this object has file attribute, this field named "pdf"
In the TCA this field I defined like this:

```
 'pdf' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:locations/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_locations_domain_model_location.pdf',
    'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
       'files', array(
          'appearance' => array(
             'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference',   
          ),
          'size' => 1,
          'minitems' => 0,
          'maxitems' => 1,
       ), $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
    )   
 ),
```

And now I can upload a file or image for this field, but there are some things does not good:

1. I want to allow PDF files only
2. After upload one file, if I upload another file, is said that "The existing files be overwritten" but old file never be overwritten. 
   The new one is also not uploaded.

What I need for this case: If I upload a new file, the old file will be overwritten by the new one.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass in `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']` you are currently allowing all kind of image-like file extensions. This is the point where you might want to use `'pdf'` instead.

If you want to overwrite files, you'll need to to this in the File module of TYPO3. If you want to put a different file in your relation, you can remove the current one and add another one. The first file won't be deleted automatically but your record will have a relation to the new file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So, there is not any way to remove the current one automatically? So, why there is a warning "Existing files will be overwritten"? But it does not do anything?
I just need to do remove the old one without clicking delete icon, just upload new one and the old one automatically be replaced with new one.